# How to use Queue::late in laravel 4.2?

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon, laravel-4.2

I have a database with points, and want to subtract the points I just added after a year.
I figured I would use a queue job and subtract my points later. I followed this official laravel link: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queues#queueing-closures

Here is a snippet:

```
DB::table('users')->where('id', $user_id)->increment('points_single', $points);
                        
//create the date when the points should be subtracted
$date = Carbon::now()->addMinutes(120);
                        
                        
//push the job onto the queue
Queue::later($date, function($job) use ($user_id, $points)
{
   DB::table('users')->where('id', $user_id)->decrement('points_single', $points);
                         
   $job->delete();
});
```

The problem is the job runs instantly, even though I specified a new date time. Why is that?

Comment: It may depend on which queue you're using. Though if you want to remove the points after a year, you probably want a cron-schedule command to do that. And I'll add in the obligatory "4.2 is extremely out of date, you really should upgrade to the newest version as soon as you can".

Comment: You're probably using `Sync` as your queue, where there's no way to set a delay and all jobs are executed as quickly as possible.
Check the configuration: `/app/config/queue.php`

Comment: @aynber how would I go about programatically creating cron jobs from a controller

Comment: I wouldn't create it from the controller. You can [create a command](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/commands) that can be used on the command line, and scheduled with cron. This can be used to modify multiple users at once.

Comment: @aynber I see it uses artisan make, is there a way to not use that function and just create the file myself?

Comment: Sure I don't see why not. Just make sure you extend Command and follow the conventions for it. `command:make` is just easier because it creates the stubbed class for you.

Comment: *"is there a way to not use that function"* - I personally rarely use the `{thing}:make` commands myself, since they create the files with the incorrect indentation ("incorrect" of course being a subjective term; my team prefers 2 spaces over the default 4 spaces) and I need to change it after the fact. You can simply copy an existing Command (assuming you have one), rename it and replace the logic of the `handle()` method, or make it from scratch following the advice aynber suggests.

Comment: @TimLewis thank you Tim, now there is one last issue to fix. After creating my command, how do I run it from the cron job ?

Comment: Refer to the documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/scheduling, specifically https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler

Comment: @TimLewis i am running laravle 4.2 I dont think these link apply

Comment: There's a dropdown at the top of the documentation to swap versions; adjust it to Laravel 4.2. The main difference between 4.2 and 10 is the fact that scheduling can be done in each Command in 10.x vs a single spot in 4.2. The CRON logic is similar. That being said, you should really consider upgrading... Aynber said it already, but 4.2 is _way_ out of date (like 8+ years).

Comment: Sidenote, I see now that selecting 4.2 from the dropdown results in a 404 Page Not Found error, and I can't find the documentation for CRON scheduling for Laravel 4.2... It's there for 5.2 (https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/scheduling), but not for prior versions 

Comment: @TimLewis I opted for a more traditional approach of writing a simple PHP script that has nothing to do with Laravel to complete this task. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Totally fair. I'm like 90% sure the same approach to running the scheduler via CRON (i.e. `* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`) still works in Laravel 4.2, but again, due to age of that version, I really can't verify... Glad you got something working though; cheers!

Comment: Yes, using crontab to schedule scripts still works in 4.2. I used it that way for many years! Thought I had it as `* * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/project/artisan my:command`